# UIView is not rounded

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a small problem and not sure why it is not working. I have a code:

```
func rounded(cornerRadius: CGFloat? = nil) {
    if let cornerRadius = cornerRadius {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    } else {
        layer.cornerRadius = min(frame.size.height, frame.size.width) / 2
    }
    clipsToBounds = true
}
```

And I am trying to use like this:

```
cameraImageContainer.rounded()
```

*cameraImageContainer = UIView*

The image is not really very rounded and it doesn't look good.

[image: Camera Button]

Any Suggestions please?

Comment: In which method are you doing `cameraImageContainer.rounded()`? `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: What is the width and height of your view?

Comment: @Sweeper in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @Jkrist hmm... I would have expected that to work... Try putting it in `viewDidAppear`, or use `bounds.size` instead, or both...

Comment: @Rob width and height is 86x86

Comment: @Sweeper ghm. It works when I put it in viewDidAppear. But why? :D

Comment: You can try setting the cornerRadius in the frame { didSet {} }

Comment: @Jkrist I don't know for sure. But the frame definitely changes _after_ `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and _before_ `viewDidAppear`. Do you have any idea which part of your code might change the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the frame can change, it's easier to implement the corner radius when the bounds are set. Give this a try:

```
class CircleView: UIView {
  override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
      self.layer.cornerRadius = min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width) / 2
    }
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.commonInit()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self.commonInit()
  }

  private func commonInit() {
    clipsToBounds = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the function to round the image  in viewDidApper like this

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    cameraImageContainer.rounded()
}
```

because the frames of the button will be set only after the view is loaded 
if you waant to call it in viewDidLoad create a custom class for imageView and set it in the storybaord